# Generating special linear group of 2x2 matrices over the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have encountered the problem in Artin's Algebra. The problem is M.14 from chapter 2.

$\textbf{(2.M.14)}$ Prove that the two matrices $E=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, E'=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ generate the group $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ of all integer matrices with determinant $1$.

Can you help me either with hints or with a full solution?

Comment: This is theorem 1.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf) . Note that $S=E-E'$

Comment: @TheoC. In order to prove that theorem 1.1 is the same thing I asked, shouldn't you show that $S$ can be written as a product of matrices $E,E'$ and not as sum of them? Second question: is there an easier way to solve the problem? because I found it in the second chapter of the book and those topics have not been covered yet

Comment: I want to say that this is the LU decomposition, or something like it. I will try to turn that into a proof!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't double-checked this, but it seems to work.

Let $X$ denote the set of matrices $M$ such that $M\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but $M\not\in \langle E,E'\rangle$. Write $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, and note that if $b=0$ then $a=d=1$, and $M$ is a power of $E$. Thus $b\neq 0$ for all matrices in $X$. Choose a matrix such that $|b|$ is minimal, and then among them choose one so that $|d|$ is minimal.

Premultiply by $\begin{pmatrix}1&\alpha\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, a power of $E'$. We obtain
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\alpha\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+\alpha c&b+\alpha d\\c&d\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly $b+\alpha d$ can be chosen to have smaller modulus unless $|d|\geq 2|b|$. But now we premultiply by $E^\alpha$ instead to obtain $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\\alpha&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c+\alpha a&d+\alpha b\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this case, $\alpha$ can be chosen so that $|d+\alpha b|<|d|$, and thus our original choice was not minimal, a contradiction. Thus $|X|=0$.

Comment: What if $|d| = 2|b|$? Both of the inequalities are not satisfied for any $\alpha$ integer

Comment: If $d=2b$ then $|d-b|<|d|$.

Comment: If $b=0$, then $a=d=1$ **or** $a=d=-1$.

Comment: I also failed to see how you arrived at the condition $|d|\geq 2|b|$.

Comment: If $|b|>|d|$, then $|b+d|<|b|$ or $|b-d|<|b|$. Otherwise,  $|b+d|\ge|b|$ and $|b-d|\ge|b|$. By adding these two inequalities we get $|d|\ge|b|$, a contradiction. Similarly, if $|b|<|d|$, then $|b+d|<|d|$ or $|b-d|<|d|$. If $|b|=|d|$ we can replace $b$ by $0$.

Comment: The case $a=d=-1$ can be handled if one notice that $-I_2$ belongs to the subgroup generated by $E$ and $E'$.